# How can i select multiple date columns in a dataframe in pandas, then format them all ? (python)

Tags: python, datetime, dateformatter

I have a large dataset with multiple date columns that I need to clean up, mostly by removing the time stamp since it is all 00:00:00. I want to write a function that collects all columns if type is datetime, then format all of them instead of having to attack one each.

Comment: Go through all the columns and check the `dtype` of each? Then you have a list of date columns you can iterate through and clean in a loop.

Comment: Share the code which you tried. Where exactly are you failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is what I came up with and it works for me:

```
def tidy_dates(df):
    for col in df.select_dtypes(include="datetime64[ns, UTC]"):
        df[col] = df[col].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    return df
```